# How much has changed since the start of One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

I recently started watching One Piece, and noticed as I reached episode 590 that the animation quality seems to have changed quite a bit since episode 1.

Now I was wondering, are there any other big changes they made since episode one besides quality changes? And how did they do those quality changes? I did not notice any changes until quite a bit in. Is there some particular technique they used?

So, summed up, this is my question.

- What are the big changes in quality/animation they have made since the start?
- Are there any other big changes they made besides quality?
- How did they do the quality changes?

Comment: As far as I remember till the Skypiea Arc they used the 4:3 canvas and after that they started using the full widescreen canvas .

Comment: Nami's breasts have grown extensively as the show continued.

Comment: Haki broke logia. Before they were practically unbeatable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The anime moved to Bandai Entertainment since Episode 205, and then it started to run in widescreen and not 4:3.
Quality changes are just because this anime exists for about 15 years, so it's only natural for the video quality itself to improve over time.
Edit: In the anime, the change between old One Piece and new One Piece is alot more clear than in the manga. The quality of the animation started being alot better after One Piece moved to Bandai Entertainment.

Yes there are big changes.
Episodes 517+ happen in a time called "post-timeskip" and in "the new world".
Episodes 1-516 are referred as "pre-timeskip", because after episode 400 alot of big things happen, and they change the whole world of One Piece, but I'm not going to spoil your experience, I can just tell you this: enjoy the East Blue saga, expect big things and surprises, and have fun.

Comment: Oh you wont spoil me :p i am up to date with the manga. As for the big changes I was more talking in a animative way. Did they change total style, and how did they manage to do the quality change. The quality surely went up, but you barely notice the transfer from old to new quality unless you look back.

Comment: In the Anime it is alot easier to notice the change in the quality, because after episode 205, the difference between Bandai's One Piece and Not Bandai's One Piece is pretty clear. I still miss Not Bandai's One Piece though.

Comment: Well tbh I did not notice the quality switch when they switched to bandai. offcourse the 4:3 to widescreen I did. maybe you should include some of those changes in your answer. Then I think it will be acceptable answer ;)

Comment: Okay, I have added that.

Answer (score 3):

A big change is related to openings and endings. There is no more endings, only big openings with about 2 minutes. The animation canvas are bigger too: before it was in 4:3, now its widescreen

Comment: Nice points, But it does not fully answer my question yet. Mind expanding your answer a bit more ? other wise you should consider posting it as a comment once you reach 20 reputation :)

Answer (score 2):

The One Piece anime started in 2002. For episode 1–204, screen size ratio = 4:3. From episode 205 onward, it's widescreen 16:9. These points have already been mentioned in other answers. However, I'll add the following which might have affected quality (my speculation):

1. Improved technology.
2. HD quality came much later, maybe around 2005.
3. Although the episode length is the same (23 minutes), the size has increased (60 MB and more), though it is because of HD quality.
4. Improved encoding of audio and video, again related to HD.
5. More processing capacity of screens.

Mostly, the quality improved because of technological advancement. For more details, maybe ask the Bandai team. ;)